# How to remove certain rows that exist in one table from another table using a common column

Tags: marketing-cloud

So i have two data extensions, Table 1 and 2 have the exact same 5 columns

One of the common columns is called "ECIF_ID" and what i'm trying to do is take all the rows that exist in table 2 and exclude them from table 1 by ECIF_ID

Can anyone please assist with the SQL Query for this?

Answer (score 0):

Asuuming you want keep data in table 1 that do not exist in Table 2:

```
Select a.field1, a.field2,a.field3, a.field4, a.field5
From table1 a
Where not exists(Select 1 
                  From table2 b 
                  Where b.ECIF_ID = a.ECIF_ID
                 )
```

Comment: If other way around, then switch table names in outer/inner query.

Comment: No I want to remove all rows in table 1 that exist in table 2

Comment: Ok. Then my code would do just that. Remember, you have to have another NEW DE to store final result.

Comment: It's giving me an error saying "a.ECIF_ID" could not be bound

Comment: Have you done these steps:
 1) create NEW Data Extension (replicate Table 1 DE) to store new data 
 2) run this code (above) in Automation SQL Activity and selected this NEW DE as the Target

Comment: @zuzannamj - Glad you added the SQL JOINs Chart.   I'm sure it is helpful for those people who're SQL Newbies.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a left join:

[image]

```
SELECT a.field1, a.field2, a.field3, a.field4, a.ECIF_ID
FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ECIF_ID = b.ECIF_ID
WHERE b.ECIF_ID IS NULL
```